# Android - Is it good we use enum as key in HashMap<MyEnum, String> in place of String?

Tags: java, collections, enums, hashmap

Should we use Enum as key in `HashMap<MyEnum, String>` to store data in place of String Key Ex. 
`HashMap<String, String> myMap`

Is there any performance issue with enum as key in HashMap as compare to the string. Which one is the most elegant way of using the Map?

Answer (score 0):

Why wouldn‘t you use the more strongly typed Enum? Avoid String wherever you can use a more appropriate type.

Performance wise it shouldn’t make any difference, if Enum isn’t  even be better, because it’s guaranteed, that there’s only one single instance around. (Same is probably true for Strings, because they are usually interned by the complier).

As a general rule I wouldn’t worry about low level optimizations like these too much. If in doubt, test, test, test.

Answer (score 0):

If performance is an issue to you, I'd suggest you'd better use `java.util.EnumMap`, which is a type of Map wich uses an Enum as keys, and so, the internal storage is implemented through arrays, and indexing is done directly through unique integers, avoiding thus hash values computation.

Comment: Actually, I'm getting a response in key-value pair from back-end API and I need both key and value where keys are fixed(Ex. 5 keys--> item1,item2,item3,item4, etc) so I was thinking to use an enum as key in the Map for response mapping(Gson library) to avoid any other key if received by setting default Enum value ERROR. 
So, Will it fine to use EnumMap in this use case?

Comment: Yes, I think so. Give it a try.